Puppeteer Timeout error when it's waiting for selector on docker
I have an application running in Docker, when I run it on my machine with headless new, it works normally, but when I run it in Docker it doesn't find the selector, I've already tried all the alternatives using waitForSelector
my Dockerfile
FROM node:slim

# We don't need the standalone Chromium

# Install Google Chrome Stable and fonts
# Note: this installs the necessary libs to make the browser work with Puppeteer.
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install gnupg wget -y && \
wget --quiet --output-document=- https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | gpg --dearmor > /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/google-archive.gpg && \
sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' && \
apt-get update && \
apt-get install google-chrome-stable -y --no-install-recommends && \
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable

# Create working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy project files to container
COPY . .

# Install NPM dependencies for function
RUN npm install

# Expose app
EXPOSE 3050

# Run app
CMD ["npx", "nodemon", "server.js"]

my script:
await page.type('[id="login-input"]', pEmail, { delay: this.typeDelay });
    setTimeout(async function () {
       await page.click('[type="submit"]');
    }, 3000);
  await page.waitForNavigation();


There is no waitForSelector() in your code shown here. Please share a [mcve]--your full code, the page under test and the full stack trace of your error. But the snippet you've shown isn't correct--the setTimeout isn't connected to any promise chain, so it'll interleave arbitrarily with the main line promise code. Use await Promise.all([page.waitForNavigation(), page.click('[type="submit"]')]) instead.

Maybe you need more RAM? Use page.screenshot() to see what's happening if there's no good error trace.
